# How can I make PHP for loop work with $x on changing css background image?

Tags: php, html, css, for-loop

Here is my new code. I can't get the for loop to work.. It's only working for $x = 1 but does not run through up to 5..

```html
<?php for ($x=1; $x<=5; $x++) { ?>
<div class="active item">
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('<?php echo onepage_get_option("onepage_sliderimage" . $x); ?>');">
<div class="container">
<h3 class="carousel_headline"><?php echo onepage_get_option('onepage_sliderimage' . $x . '_heading_middle'); ?></h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `onepage_get_option('onepage_sliderimage$x');` $x will just be treated as part of the string, you would need to do `onepage_get_option('onepage_sliderimage' . $x);` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in single quotes do not work. Use like this

This works

```
echo "$x"
```

This does not

```
echo '$x'
```

Use it like this

```
"onepage_sliderimage" . $x

'onepage_sliderimage' . $x . '_heading_middle'
```

Comment: thank you!! i updated the code snippet, cause now i realized the for loop is not working.. can you help me? thanks

Comment: @JohanBrolin I don't see a reason for loop not to work. Just inspect result page and check if all html code is there.